# Send a list of objects whose information is obtained by asynchronous functions

Tags: dictionary, promise

I hope I can express myself a way you can all understand.

Here's the thing, I'm developing a back-end for an app in nodeJS. There's a table named 'chat' in dynamoDB with the ID of the chat's creator and a list of messages IDs, also there's a table named 'messages' with the author of each message and the text.
When the front-end asks the server for all the chats it has to send a list of chats objects with this sctructure:

```
   [
        {
            "ID_CHAT": {
                "S": "asd123asd"
            },
            "author": {
                 "name": "Name",
                 "lastname": "Lastname"
            },
            "date": {
                "S": "19/11/2017 16:00"
            },
            "USER_DESTINATION": {
                "S": "222asd222"
            },
            "messages": [
                {
                    "Item": {
                        "author": {
                            "name": "Name",
                            "lastname": "Lastname"
                        },
                        "text": {
                            "S": "Hi!"
                        },
                        "MESSAGE_ID": {
                            "S": "456asd456"
                        },
                        "date": {
                            "S": "19/11/2017 16:05"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Item": {
                        "author": {
                            "name": "Name",
                            "lastname": "Lastname"
                        },
                        "text": {
                            "S": "zup?"
                        },
                        "MESSAGE_ID": {
                            "S": "789asd789"
                        },
                        "date": {
                            "S": "19/11/2017 16:06"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "ID_CHAT": {
                "S": "123asd123asd"
            },
            "author": {
                "S": "123asd123"
            }, and so on...
    ]
```

But in order to send this I need to get the chat's authors data from dynamodb (asynchronous function) and the list of messages data again from dynamodb.
I tried combining map() to get the chats authors and Promise.all() for the messages but it won't work cause the second iteration of the map() function runs after the Promise.then().

I'll appretiate your help!

Comment: `I tried` - to be perfectly honest, it looks like you tried nothing at all - if you add the code you tried, someone may then be able to point out where your code is wrong. As it stands, there's absolutely no way anybody can help because there's not code to help with - common errors are forgetting to return something from a function - not sure why, but a lot of people when dealing with Promises seem to think that there's an implied "return" when using a Promise

Comment: Theanks Jaromanda for your response. I didn't have the code cause I didn't know where to start, but finally I could run into a solution and it's working great, I used a Promise.all() function inside another and the first one returned the result of the second one.